# Installed module is not working (windows)

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

So long story short. I want to use requests and bs4 modules in my code. I installed them using pip install requests, pip install bs4. I double checked everything, even found installation folder and saw that the files is here, but my vs code is not detecting it and giving a error. I'm a quite new to this programming language so possibly it's a common issue. But i searched and mostly found posts about this problems on diffrent versions of linux, not windows.

Error i'm getting in vscode btw

```
Import "requests" could not be resolved from source
```

And when i'm launching the program through cmd the error is

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: con you import the modules when you run python from your cmd? Do you ahve multiple python versions installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should add more information for us to know how your computer and IDE are configured. The first thing you should do is to check that VS Code is using the Python version where you have pip installed the modules. That is, clicking at the bottom-left space as in the picture below. Then checking that the modules are within that path.

[image]

Otherwise, check out [virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/). With this tool you can create virtual environments within your project's folder and makes it easier to manage packages.

Comment: So i did what yo said, and i  saw 3 versions. 3.7.8 64bit, 3.9.1 64bit, and 3.9.1 64bit in another folder. After picking 3.9.1 that are located in local/microsoft/windowsapps/python.exe visual studio stopped showing errors, but cmd is still not launching code

Comment: can you add what errors the cmd is rising?

Comment: D:\Py\Discord>main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Py\Discord\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: Okay, try entering in the cmd the following: 'python3 -V' (check the python version). Then write 'pip -V' and check if the two versions match. If they do, try installing the packages again. If they don't, try going for virtual environments

Comment: D:\Py\Discord>python3 -V
Python 3.9.1

D:\Py\Discord>pip -V
pip 21.0.1 from C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

Comment: Is the python version path in VS Code C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\ ?

Comment: The one i picked is not python39. I did this because when picking Python39 the modules still remain undetected

Comment: Okay, plan B: follow this tutorial on how to install virtualenv and create virtual environments: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/ then go to your project's folder, create one there, activate it and install the modules.